# MAMP pro is caching

Tags: macos, caching, mamp

I use MAMP Pro 5 for making PHP / MySQL code on OSx. Now I have the following problem, if I make a change in my code, I must first stop and start the MAMP to see the changes.
I have the Memcache off. Yet it seems like this stays on.

Comment: Are you sure the caching is on the server, not the client?

Answer (score 6):

From the menu on the left, click on "php", then set "cache module..." to "off"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should disable opcache in your MAMP console/window?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone on MAMP Pro for OSX (Monterey), the PHP setting can be accessed through the "View Mode" toggle (to "Expert" mode). By default, it's set to "Standard" mode and hides many of these options.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Cache Modul to speed up execution => Set OFF